# Share Screen problems with Wayland

Tags: 22.04, vnc, wayland

I use Wayland on my Ubuntu machine because I want to use a new Zoom feature on the Google Chrome Browser.

After that I got problems with Discord and VNC. On Discord when I share my screen it only shows a black display, nontheless I can share any application just fine. On VNC Server it seems that the app doesn't even start removing the ability to access my computer remotely.

Is there any known fix?